# How to show a marker (aka secondary texture) on a sphere at a specific location using shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I have a 3D Earth and I would like to show some specific marker at a specific location based of latitude and longitude. I figured out how to calculated world coordinates from Lat|Long and pass it to the Planet Shader. I also figured out how to show other texture at a specific location based on a texture coordinates (which is 2D).

But what I am struggling with is how can I 'flatten' 3D world coordinates to 2D texture coordinates?

All I have is a 3D coordinates for a middle point of where texture should be placed. If there was a way to calculate a 2D positions of the current 3D point, that Shader is processing at the moment and that middle point, that would give me a chance to decide whether it should be original Earth texture or the small marker texture displayed at that specific point.

This is a piece of shader that currently draws my marker based of a texture 2D coordinates:

```
    float x = IN.uv_MainTex.x * 8192;
    float y = IN.uv_MainTex.y * 4096;

    if (x > 4096 && x < 4096 +24
        && y > 2048 && y < 2048 + 24
        && tex2D(_AlienMap, float2((x - 4096) / 24, (y - 2048) / 24)).r < 0.8) {
        o.Albedo = tex2D(_AlienMap, float2((x - 4096) / 24, (y - 2048) / 24)).rgb;

        if (abs(distance(_mousePoint, float3(50, -20, 3185))) < 50)
            o.Emission = float3(1, 1, 0);
        else
            o.Emission = float3(1, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: What does your marker look like? It may also help if you can show us the UV unwrap used by the sphere model you're working with.

Comment: Think of a marker as an abstract 24x24 texture, it could be anything, circle, triangle, or something more specific in the future. I also do not know how to show you UV unwrap, I do not have specific UV mapping. It is standard 3d sphere in Unity with high-res textures (diffuse, bump blended in shader).